# Azure Stream Analytics Query - Doing a Merge

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

Good Day

I have an app that passes data via an Azure EventHub through Azure Stream Analytics in Azure SQL Database. This data is from a file that gets written from Cost Recovery Software every few minutes containing the latest FULL list of accounts.

I want to ensure that when all the data from the file gets passed through this process that some form of MERGE occurs to only update existing accounts and insert non-existing account. To ensure duplicate accounts are not created.

I am not sure if Stream Analytics is the best option to feed the data from the EventHub to SQL.

Example of Process:

[image]

Comment: UPDATE: I have read up a bit more and Data Factory seems to be a good way to do an UPSERT

Comment: However this is not as real time as Stream Analytics

Comment: You might want to use an Azure Function to do the Upsert

Answer (score 1):

Using Azure Stream Analytics and SQL Azure DB, this can be done by:

1. Output ASA data to SQL to a first table, it will be a "landing table"
2. [Create a trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in SQL to do a merge from the landing table to a final table.

Alternatively, if you use Cosmos DB as output, Azure Stream Analytics natively supports upsert, so this can be done directly from ASA.

Let us know if you have any further question and feedback.

Thanks,

JS

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you still could use Azure Data Factory to implement your real-time requirements.

1.Create [Event Hub Trigger Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs).Please see this [C# example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#trigger---c-example).

2.Create Pipeline in Azure Data Factory.

3.In that pipeline,create [Azure Function Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) to configure your event hub trigger function url and parameters.

4.Create [Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) after Azure Function Activity to make the source as the data from the output of Azure Function Activity.

5.Make the sink as SQL database and create stored procedure to do the upsert merge business.Please follow the details from this [blog](https://www.taygan.co/blog/2018/04/20/upsert-to-azure-sql-db-with-azure-data-factory).

Comment: So the UPSERT happens in Azure SQL anyways?

Comment: @LordRofticus Yes,any concern with that?

Comment: I might be missing the point but seems like a lot of Azure components is needed (and they only transport data) when the Upsert SP is doing what I want to do. That means I can just as well directly call the SP instead, send it the record values as parameters, have it check if such a record exist, and then decide INSERT/UPDATE.

Comment: @LordRofticus Yes,however you still need Azure Tirgger Function and ADF to implement the automatic job,am i right?