# Extract incremental live data ingestion from salesforce using Change Data Capture

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory, streaming, azure-eventhub

I have successfully copied data from Salesforce to my Azure SQL Database using Azure Data Factory pipelines, and I want to ensure that my pipeline automatically retrieves updated or new entries from Salesforce into my database. I am considering using Change Data Capture event from Salesforce and subscribing to the event using Azure Function or Event Hub. Can someone advise me on the best way to achieve this? Additionally, I want to ensure that any deleted rows in Salesforce are updated in my Azure SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

The CDC function in ADF doesnt support salesforce as source (or something like SAP CDC in ADF Dataflow), and sources are very limited, so as you said you can create an EventHub as source, and write delta loads of upserts and deletes coming out of that hub.

A good way to do can be to use something like Azure Streaming Analytics or its open-source equivalents to stream the data out of this hub directly into your Azure SQL DB, to a staging table that you can later use to delta load to the tables to be updated, you can truncate these staging tables after each load. For this process you can either use ADF or stored procedures inside your DB (or something like SSIS, if thats your style). The transformation place should take inside the DB because Azure Streaming Analytics is not really an ETL tool, but rather an analytical tool. This process would be like ELT, because you are transforming/processing in the final destination.

ASA does not support MERGE statements so you cant actually do upserts only with that tool, you need to write SQL logic or a data pipeline to handle that load

[Azure Stream Analytics Query - Doing a Merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295627/azure-stream-analytics-query-doing-a-merge)

[Azure SQL DB as an ASA output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/sql-database-output)